# Изменить язык перевода на русский или украинский

Tags: python, python-3.x, распознавание-речи, google-speech-recognition

У меня есть рабочий код на python, который распознает слова с wav:

```
r = sr.Recognizer()
with sr.AudioFile("sss3.wav") as source:
    audio = r.record(source)
try:
    s = r.recognize_google(audio)
    print("Text: "+s)
except Exception as e:
    print("Exception: "+str(e))
```

Я использую библиотеку speech_recognition:

```
import speech_recognition as sr
```

Но этот код распознает только английский.
Как я могу изменить распознавания на русский и украинский?

Comment: Немного погуглив разработчиками поддерживается только французкий, китайский, итальянский через установку language pack  отсюда https://github.com/Uberi/speech_recognition/blob/master/reference/pocketsphinx.rst#installing-other-languages   Про Ру и Укр ничего не заявлено. Видимо никак.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Согласно [исходнику](https://github.com/Uberi/speech_recognition/blob/master/speech_recognition/__init__.py#L845), там есть параметр `language`, который по-умолчанию равен "en-US".

Попробуйте для украинского:

```
r.recognize_google(audio, language="uk-UA")
```

или так для русского:

```
r.recognize_google(audio, language="ru-RU")
```

Comment: Спасибо, все работает